# Padding quotes in JSONObject

Tags: java, android, json

I'm building a JSON string to send to my web service.  Since one of the pieces is user-inputted, there is the possibility for double quotes.  I'm trying to resolve the issue by escaping it.

```
String strValue = "height of 6\"";
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
json.put("key", strValue.replaceAll("\"","\\\""));
```

The problem here is when I do `json.toString()`, I get 3 slashes.

Ex:

```
{"key","height of 6\\\""}
```

If I don't try to do any replacing, `json.toString()` gives me broken json.

Ex:

```
{"key", "height of 6""}
```

How can I do this correctly?

Note: When my website saves this value and displays it, it displays `height of 6\"`

UPDATE:

It appears the culprit is `json.toString()`

When I call the `replaceAll` method it -- correctly -- only escapes the double quote.  It appears `json.toString()` escapes slashes.  To fix the issue, I must do `json.toString().replace("\\\\", "")`.  This begs the question: Why on Earth does JSONObject escape slashes and not double quotes?????

Comment: What language is your web service running?

Comment: You say user-inputted, but then you define it from a string literal. That's not the same. Can you post the code that captures the inputted value?

Comment: The code provided is example code, not actual code.  That is not really relevant.

Comment: @Mike D, my web site is LAMP (php)

Comment: @Andrew While I can not give a complete answer because I do not work in Java that much, I had the same issue a few weeks ago. Our version of php was the culprit. We do not have have version that supports all the options in json_decode.  Hope this points you in the right direction.

Comment: Have you tried replacing all occurrences of `"` with `\\"`?

Comment: The question I have is, if you're replacing `"` with `\"` (before putting), then why is the output `\\\"`? This implies that both the slash, *and* the quote were escaped, doesn't it?

Comment: @Vidas Yes. See my update on the main post.  I will also post this as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears the culprit is `json.toString()`

When I call the replaceAll method it -- correctly -- only escapes the double quote. It appears `json.toString()` escapes slashes. To fix the issue, I must do `json.toString().replace("\\\\", "")`.

This begs the question: Why on Earth does JSONObject escape slashes and not double quotes?????