# JSONObject losing escaped characters

Tags: java, json

I want to convert from string to json object in Java.

source :

```
String path = "{ \"path\" : \"C:\\ddd\\c.java\" }";
JSONObject json_test = new JSONObject(path);
System.out.println(json_test.toString());
```

expected result :

```
{ "path" : "c:\ddd\c.java" }
```

real result :

```
{ "path" : "c:dddc.java" }
```

how can i keep `\\` (backslash) at JSONObject ?

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13420115/padding-quotes-in-jsonobject

Answer (score 0):

easiest way to make use of `/` . Both works fine in window.

```
"{ \"path\" : \"C:/ddd/c.java\" }"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
 org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava(str)
```